# Call an event from father to child - Angular 5.2.1

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a call from a parent component to a child with Angular 5.2.1

```
// view parent

<child-component #child></chrild-component>    

// controller parent
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;

detalle(parte: GestionImputacionData) {
    this.parentVerTabla = false;
    this.child.cargar(parte);
}


// Controller child
cargar(parte: GestionImputacionData) {
    this.parte = parte;
    //more things
}
```

I've seen some examples, and I think I'm doing well, but the son does not hear about the father's event, and I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How exactly are you calling `detalle` in your Parent Component?

Comment: <tr (click)="detalle(parte)"> When I click on a row I want to pass that value to the child and I also have to process the data, so I need to call a function of the child.

Comment: Check if my answer helps. If it doesn't I'd urge you to fork my stackblitz, implement your changes so that your issue could be replicated, and then share the updated stackblitz so that I could have a look.

Comment: Also you have a spelling mistake `<child-component #child></chrild-component>` *chrild*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<child-component #child></chrild-component> <- here is your mistake
```

it should be

```
<child-component #child></child-component>
```

i tried with same approach its working

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p2ahqf

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `ChildComponent` type in your ParentComponent, you don't really need the template variable `#child` in your Parent Template:

**`<child-component #child></chrild-component>`** can be reduced to **`<child-component></child-component>`**

In the ending tag of your ChildComponent, it's `chrild-component`. Not really sure if that's a typo.

Also, you probably are not calling `detalle` in your Parent Component which in turn is responsible to call the `cargar` method in your `ChildComponent`. So make sure that you're doing that.

Finally, make sure that you're calling the `detalle` method only once `ngAfterViewInit` has been called.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-child-method-from-parent-via-view-child?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.